# Bubble chart clustering layout

Tags: javascript, d3.js, bubble-chart

I am creating my first bubble chart using d3.v4 and I would like to group some of the bubbles into the clusters. How I can do that? Here is my code

```
dataset = {
    "children": [{
        "facilityId": "Montgomery Region",
        "responseCount": 1
    }, {
        "facilityId": "PG South",
        "responseCount": 2
    }, {
        "facilityId": "PG Central",
        "responseCount": 4
    }, {
        "facilityId": "Baltimore City South",
        "responseCount": 5
    }, {
        "facilityId": "Baltimore City Northeast",
        "responseCount": 5
    }, {
        "facilityId": "Baltimore County East",
        "responseCount": 6
     }, {
        "facilityId": "Baltimore City Northwest",
        "responseCount": 7
    }, {
        "facilityId": "Batimore County West",
        "responseCount": 8
    }]
};

var diameter = 600;
var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);

var bubble = d3.pack(dataset)
        .size([diameter, diameter])
        .padding(1.5);
var svg = d3.select(".chart")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", diameter)
        .attr("height", diameter)
        .attr("class", "bubble");

var nodes = d3.hierarchy(dataset)
        .sum(function(d) { return d.responseCount; });

var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
        .data(bubble(nodes).descendants())
        .enter()
        .filter(function(d){
            return  !d.children
        })
        .append("g")
        .attr("class", "node")
        .attr("transform", function(d) {
            return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
        });

node.append("title")
        .text(function(d) {
            return d.facilityId + ": " + d.responseCount;
        });

node.append("circle")
        .attr("r", function(d) {
            return d.r;
        })
        .style("fill", function(d) {
            return color(Math.random());
        });

node.append("text")
        .attr("dy", ".3em")
        .style("text-anchor",  "middle")
        .text(function(d) {
            return d.data.facilityId.substring(0, d.r / 3) ;
        });

d3.select(self.frameElement)
        .style("height", diameter + "px");
```

and this is the output I am having

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AxTcC.jpg)

And here is also my jsfiddle.

[enter link description here](https://jsfiddle.net/Vinill/r24e8xd7/54/#&togetherjs=qybb7rxewE)

I need to have something similar to that, only without a bigger circle containing all its childs

Comment: you want only the text ?

Comment: What do u mean? Yeah l need to see only labels on the bubbles

Comment: I need for example combine all Baltimore City regions into one cluster

Comment: can you modify the json ? and do you have list of cities/regions ?

Comment: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/ca5b03a33affa4160321